# Firestore One-to-Many Relationship Query

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I need help, how to make one-to-many queries, for example:

I have 2 collections: `customers`, `orders`

```
customers{
   customerId,
   fullName,   
   company,
   email,
}
orders{
   orderId,
   customerId,
   createdAt,
}
```

[image]
I want to list all orders in a table with some customers data (customer full name, compa

Answer (score -1):

Congratulations, you are alone in the dark Firestore Forest. Bring back all you have learned of DBMS at the college days and get you hands dirty.

Alternative 1:

First you need to filter the customers that satisfies your criteria. Then, load ALL your orders and filter mannually. I'm not kidding, saddly. The same applies if you need to order orders by customer name, for example. I'll be very happy to see someone downvote this for being wrong.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Alternative 2:

Stop using Firestore. I think you already done that.